# Keeping in (http)context over multiple modules

Tags: asp.net, httpcontext, null-coalescing-operator

I have a class with static functions which need to use the current `HttpContext`. Instead of sending the object each time I use these functions, I tried a different approach. I built such a property:

```
private static HttpContext _http;
private static HttpContext http
{
    get
    {
        if (_http == null)
           _http = HttpContext.Current;
        return _http;
    }
    set { _http = value; }
}
```

In the functions I use `http` as my `HttpContext`.

The thing it it seems unstable. Is there some problem with this?

**UPDATE:**
I found this works nicely

```
    get
    {
        return _http ?? HttpContext.Current;
    }
```

Explanations please

Answer (score 0):

What on Earth made you to create a setter and a backing field? Wouldn't it be much easier to have only the getter, which returns a current http context?

```
protected static HttpContext Http
{
    get
    {
        return HttpContext.Current;
    }
}
```

By the way:

I do like much private properties, you could either make it `protected` for the ancestors or make it a method:

```
private static HttpContext GetCurrentContext() 
{
    return HttpContext.Current;
}
```

Comment: I don't want it to change once it was set so the context stays the same across different modules. I think. Been a while, I don't really remember myself.

Comment: @JNF The context changes the next time you accept incoming request.